# Unable to remove Java 17 from MacBook Air M1

Tags: java, macos, operating-system, uninstallation

I tried to remove Java using sudo rm -rf "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines" as mentioned on Oracle docs, still Java 17 is being shown to me, after uninstalling it from my system.
Any pointer to remove Java from MacBook?

```
arvindsangwan@Arvinds-MacBook-Air ~ % java -version
    openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-39)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)
    arvindsangwan@Arvinds-MacBook-Air ~ % cd /Library/Java                               
    arvindsangwan@Arvinds-MacBook-Air Java % ls
    arvindsangwan@Arvinds-MacBook-Air Java %
```

Comment: You may be able to get a better answers on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ as uninstalling Java is only tangentially related to the topic of StackOverflow (programming). There is also a YouTube video titled "Remove Java JDK from Macbook M1" that may help.

Answer (score 4):

Steps I performed were from here : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html

1. In the Terminal window Copy, Paste and run the commands below (one by one) :

   ```
   sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
   sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
   sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
   ```
2. Then after successfully uninstalling Java, you may remove Java Deployment cache:
   In the Terminal window Copy and Paste the commands below:

   ```
   rm -r ~/"Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java"
   ```
3. then remove the jdk folder and it's content:

   ```
   sudo rm -r -f /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<"your_version">.jdk
   ```
4. then perform the holy **computer restart** .

If you have more than 1 java version installed you may also find useful the info from this page: https://java.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-switch-java-version-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

➜check your java version
java -version
java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS

Change the working path to java virtual machines
➜  ~ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
check your JDK here by ls command

➜  JavaVirtualMachines ls

jdk-17.0.2.jdk

➜  JavaVirtualMachines sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk
Password:
➜  JavaVirtualMachines ls
➜  JavaVirtualMachines sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
➜  JavaVirtualMachines sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
➜  JavaVirtualMachines sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing Java from your system with these commands

`rm` will remove the specified file or directory.

options
-r If it's a directory, it will remove all its contents recursively, including subdirectories/files and their contents.
-f Do this forcefully without asking for confirmation for each files and folders.

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk[version].jdk`

Example:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk
```

Additional Files/Folders

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```